# "Add to VCS" disabled in Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio

I have been using Intellij IDEA w/git integration for Android dev for sometime. I have recently upgraded to Android Studio (v0.1.1) and now one of my favorite shortcuts Ctrl+Command+A "Add to VCS" is always disabled. Is this a bug or a GIT setting I am missing?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It shouldn't be disabled. Does your file actually have any changes? Is it shown in the changes view?

Comment: Yes, 'git status' shows changes not staged for commit on this file.

Comment: facing same kind of problem in android studio 2.2.2. Android Studio can't detect a file is added & does not show any option to add it. I am using SVN for this.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. At the first place you initialize git and add files for tracking, some files asked to add to git. when you ignore it and check **"do not ask / remember"** they add to  `.gitignore` file.

just open `.gitignore` file and check if the specific folder is included so remove it and the gray color of folder and files will change to red and you can add them simply.

hope work for you

Answer (score 0):

Add File to git means, that this file doesn´t exist before in git and is newly created ... if you change a file use commit ;)

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked **3 years ago** and probably the OP isnt even following this post for an answer any more. But, for those who land on this page seeking an answer. **-** Android Studio has evolved a lot since then and all those issues are fixed. Go ahead and download the latest version as of today. It works fine at my end. Never saw that happening.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party, but this solved my problem.

Please note, that Android Studio also has its own Ignored Files list. If you can commit files with other git clients or using git in terminal, this could be the problem. In Android Studio go to `File > Settings > Version Control > Ignored Files` and remove files/folders from the list. Now you should be able to add files to git.

Answer (score -1):

You can enable it through this menu:

[image: Menu image]