# Android Studio files status gray and not changing to show VCS changes

Tags: android-studio, github, version-control

I was working on a project in Android Studio when I update my Android studio to latest stable version. After updating Android studio, it prompted me to update Project build.gradle for the project (from com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3' to com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'.
Since then most of the files are in grey colour and are not showing File Status in Views and Line Status in the Editor on making modifications to the files. It used to highlight all changes to the files since the last synchronisation with blue colour.

I have tried to revert to com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3', that didn't work. Then I tried deleting.AndroidStudio and .gradle folders from user folder, reinstalling android studio and also deleting the project from the directory and cloning a fresh copy from Github.
That fixed it for once when imported the project in the Android studio for the first time, but the problem came back after a restart.
I have checked, There are no changes to the code on GitHub that could have cause it. I only did changes to resource files
It's working fine on other projects, and just this project is having the issue so far.

[image]

I believe this is a bug in Android studio's latest update, so I have also reported the bug on Android Studio bug tracker.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223359&sort=-opened&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened

Comment: I rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate here to add [Solved] to the title. If you've found a solution and you'd like to share it, do so by writing an answer in the space below. If not, you can always wait for someone else to do so, or delete your question if you don't feel it will benefit future readers here.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had the same problem and it is solved for me in this way:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41211805/1498586